# SQL Query related to joins

Tags: database

My Database table `NAMEINFO` has two column `Name`,`Alias`.

It has following tuples

1)a a1
2)a1 a2
3)a2 -
4)b b1
5)b1 b2
6)b2 -

When i used the query

```
SELECT t1.NAME,t2.NAME 
FROM NAMEINFO t1,NAMEINFO t2
WHERE t1.ALIAS=t2.ALIAS
```

The output is

1)a a1
2)a1 a2
3)b b1
4)b1 b2.

But I want only the aliases for the name **'a'**.i.e.,my output should be
1)a a1
2)a1 a2.

How can I incorporate that condition into my query?

Comment: Not able to understand why the people are voting down,even if i keep my research work in the query.:(

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
SELECT t1.NAME
FROM NAMEINFO t1 
INNER JOIN NAMEINFO t2 ON t1.ALIAS = t2.ALIAS
```